# Override the getFocus of an external page that loads in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, focus

I have multiple pages laoding in an iframe and one of them seems to be getting focus, since the page scrolls (by itself) to that spcific iframe.

Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1):

iFrame onFocus event can be overridden to set the focus priority. But, be careful because it sometimes doesn't work with Mozilla. Also, I would prefer to use the Div and display HTML inside the Div.